# What is the most fashionable way of calculating minimum value?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, min

I want to calculate a minimum value among a set of values using a custom comparator. At the moment my code looks approximately like this:

```
SomeStructure best;
for  (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    SomeStructure cur = getValue(i);
    if (isLess(cur, best))
    {
        best = cur;
    }
}
```

I find this way not very explicit. For example, if I used a standard comparer, I could write this much prettier:

```
accumulator_set<SomeStructure, stats<tag::min>> min;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i))
{
  min(getValue(i));
}
extract::min(min);
```

So, the question is: how can I write something like the second example, but using a custom comparator?
My project uses `C++14` and `boost`, so the solution can use their features.
`C++17` is interesting, though not very useful.

**UPDATE**: looks like I was not very precise in this question.

- `getValue` is a complicated function calculating some value given its index, not just retrieving it from a container.
- I could store all the data in the container and then just use `std::min_element`, but I'm sure there's any explicit method without doing this.

Comment: `std::min_element` with a lambda does it for me.

Comment: Dior Dahhling, Dior. ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba, to use `std::min_element` I should store all the data in a container. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 it's work for C-style array too. 

`int arr[size];
std::min_element( arr, arr + size, []() { /*your lambda */} );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::min` if you wants to compare two elements or a set of elements contained in an `initializer_list`, along with a custom comparator.
See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) for further details. There is also a bunch of examples.
Otherwise, you can use `std::min_element` for a range. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) the documentation.

**EDIT**

As far as I understand from your question/comments, you don't have a container on which to iterate, instead you would like to compare a set of unrelated values.
It follows an example, that is the one available in the documentation slightly reduced:

```
std::min( { "foo", "bar", "hello" },
    [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    });
```

Use your variables instead and create the initializer list on-the-fly, no need for a container anymore.

**EDIT 2**

In regarding of the update of the question, it follows a possible solution.
You can compare two elements at a time while you iterate over the whole set. As an example, put the first element in a variable called `min`, then for each subsequent element compare `min` with the currently one you are elaborating and, if the former is greater than the latter, updated the `min` variable.
When the iteration ends, you have the `min` properly set with the element you were looking for. In this case, `std::min` with a custom comparator seems to be the best solution.

Comment: As far as I understand, to use `std::min_element` I should store all the data in a container. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 you can use `std::min` and submit your values by means of an initializer list, see the linke documentation.

Comment: could you please explain more in detail, how can I create the initializer list on-the-fly? I have too many values, and cannot just write `{getValue(0), getValue(1), ...}`

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 What's `getValue`? I don't see defined in your example. if it gets values from a container (as an example, from a `vector`), then use it and its member methods `cbegin`/`cend`. Unfortunately your example is not a MVCE, so it's hard to say how to do it exactly.

Comment: in my problem I have a 3D scene with a lot of objects and `getValue` calculates some statistics over this scene given the indexer. It contains hundreds of lines. That's why my example above contains the function call, not iterator dereferencing. Sorry for being not very precise.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 So are those objects packed in a container? Anyway, you can also compare two elements at a time while you iterate over the whole set. As an example, put the first element in a variable called `min`, then for each subsequent element compare `min` with the currently one you are elaborating and, it the former is greater than the latter, updated the `min` variable. When you have finished to iterate over all your elements, you have the `min` properly set. In this case, `std::min` with a custom comparator works fine for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97291/discussion-between-alexeykuzmin0-and-skypjack).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `std::min`, something like (assuming you've defined `operator<`) :

```
SomeStructure best;
for  (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    best = std::min(best, getValue(i));
```